# FT_Init_Freetype unresolved Symbol

Tags: c, microcontroller, freetype2

I am supposed to run run freetype on a Controller. I have added the include path directory to the compilation include path. I am using a MULTI Debugger byGreen Hills which flashes the code onto the Controller. I am unable to use the freetype functions. I am new to freetype. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You need to show the exact errors you're getting, and probably also the compiler invocation and output. It sounds as if you're failing to link to a library.

Comment: The exact error is [elxr] (error) unresolved symbols: 1
 _FT_Init_FreeType         from freetypeTest.o       The thing is the .c files in src folder are not being compiled

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but you seem slightly new to C, too.

All doing `#include` on a header does is bring the relevant function *declarations* into your program, but you generally don't get any *definitions*, i.e. the actual code.

To get those, you need to link against a file containing the relevant code.

In your case you probably should add something like `-lfreetype` to the compiler invocation when building your program:

```
$ gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lfreetype
```

Note that the order of the source file(s) and `-l` linker option(s) matter.

If you have a `Makefile` set up, look for a line declaring `LDLIBS`, and edit it to include the `-lfreetype` option.

Comment: Hello, none taken. I did try -lfreetype/src freetypeTest.c. But that's not helping.

Comment: The thing is src is the folder in which there are about 20 folders which contain n no. of .h and .c files. Again, sorry for my ignorance,. And Like I said, I am using a compiler + debugger called MULTI and not cmd line